# Column into rows and make a master table of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need insert columns data to a different table and create master table for columns

Like example : I need to convert table **tblcatData** into two tables **tblCat** and **tblcatDataNew**

**tblCatData**

```
    Primaykey | A | B | C | D | D | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1         | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
    2         | 1 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
    3         | 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
```

**tblCat**

```
    PrimaryKey | Category
----------------------------
    1          | A
    2          | B
    3          | C
    4          | D
    5          | E
    6          | F
    7          | G
    .            .
    .            .
    .            .
```

**tblCatDataNew**

```
    PrimaryKey | FK_CatID | Data |
-----------------------------------
    1          | 1        | 1    |
    2          | 1        | 1    |
    3          | 1        | 5    |
    4          | 2        | 2    |
    5          | 2        | 2    |
    6          | 2        | 2    |
    7          | 3        | 3    |
    8          | 3        | 5    |
    .            .          .
    .            .          .
    .            .          .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following scenario:

1. Create `tblCat`.
2. Create `tblCatDataNew` with the following deviations from the original design:

   - the `FK_CatID` column is allowed to accept NULLs temporarily (or maybe permanently, if that was your original intention);
   - an extra column is added temporarily to receive the category *names* from the original table.
3. Unpivot `tblCatData` and insert the results into `tblCatDataNew` (the values into  `Data` and the column names, as category names, into the temporary column).
4. Select all the distinct category names from `tblCatDataNew` and insert them into `tblCat`. (That will produce the key values for them.)
5. Update the foreign keys in `tblCatDataNew` from `tblCat`, joining the two tables by category names.
6. Drop the temporary column from `tblCatDataNew`.
7. Set `tblCatDataNew.FK_CatID` as `NOT NULL` (that is, if you wanted it to be so).

Here's the entire test script, including creation of the original table (in case someone would like to try it):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

/* prepare the original table, for tests */
WITH data (
    Primaykey, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M
) AS (
  SELECT 1   , 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2   , 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3   , 5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4
)
SELECT * INTO tblCatData FROM data;
GO

/* Step 1 */
CREATE TABLE tblCat (
  PrimaryKey int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_tblCat PRIMARY KEY,
  Category varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
GO

/* Step 2 */
CREATE TABLE tblCatDataNew (
  PrimaryKey int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_tblCatDataNew PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_CatID int NULL CONSTRAINT FK_tblCatDataNew_tblCat FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblCat (PrimaryKey),
  Data int,
  Category varchar(50)
);
GO

/* Step 3 */
INSERT INTO tblCatDataNew (
  Data,
  Category
)
SELECT
  Data,
  Category
FROM tblCatData
UNPIVOT (
  Data for Category IN (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M)
) u
ORDER BY
  Category,
  Primaykey;
GO

/* Step 4 */
INSERT INTO tblCat (Category)
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM tblCatDataNew
GO

/* Step 5 */
UPDATE tblCatDataNew
SET FK_CatID = c.PrimaryKey
FROM tblCat c
WHERE tblCatDataNew.Category = c.Category

GO

/* Step 6 */
ALTER TABLE tblCatDataNew
DROP COLUMN Category
GO

/* Step 7 */
ALTER TABLE tblCatDataNew
ALTER COLUMN FK_CatID int NOT NULL
GO

/* view the results */
SELECT * FROM tblCat
SELECT * FROM tblCatDataNew
GO

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Note that the UNPIVOT clause is supported in SQL Server starting from the 2005 version. In earlier versions you'd have to use a different method to unpivot data (Step 3), e.g. like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblCatDataNew (
  Data,
  Category
)
SELECT
  Data = CASE x.CatNum
    WHEN  1 THEN A
    WHEN  2 THEN B
    WHEN  3 THEN C
    WHEN  4 THEN D
    WHEN  5 THEN E
    WHEN  6 THEN F
    WHEN  7 THEN G
    WHEN  8 THEN H
    WHEN  9 THEN I
    WHEN 10 THEN J
    WHEN 11 THEN K
    WHEN 12 THEN L
    WHEN 13 THEN M
  END,
  Category = CASE x.CatNum
    WHEN  1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN  2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN  3 THEN 'C'
    WHEN  4 THEN 'D'
    WHEN  5 THEN 'E'
    WHEN  6 THEN 'F'
    WHEN  7 THEN 'G'
    WHEN  8 THEN 'H'
    WHEN  9 THEN 'I'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'J'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'K'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'L'
    WHEN 13 THEN 'M'
  END
FROM tblCatData
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  2 UNION ALL
    SELECT  3 UNION ALL
    SELECT  4 UNION ALL
    SELECT  5 UNION ALL
    SELECT  6 UNION ALL
    SELECT  7 UNION ALL
    SELECT  8 UNION ALL
    SELECT  9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13
  ) x (CatNum)
ORDER BY
  Category,
  Primaykey;
```

or even like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblCatDataNew (
  Data,
  Category
)
SELECT
  Data = CASE x.CatNum
    WHEN  1 THEN A
    WHEN  2 THEN B
    WHEN  3 THEN C
    WHEN  4 THEN D
    WHEN  5 THEN E
    WHEN  6 THEN F
    WHEN  7 THEN G
    WHEN  8 THEN H
    WHEN  9 THEN I
    WHEN 10 THEN J
    WHEN 11 THEN K
    WHEN 12 THEN L
    WHEN 13 THEN M
  END,
  Category = x.CatName
FROM tblCatData
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  1, 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT  2, 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT  3, 'C' UNION ALL
    SELECT  4, 'D' UNION ALL
    SELECT  5, 'E' UNION ALL
    SELECT  6, 'F' UNION ALL
    SELECT  7, 'G' UNION ALL
    SELECT  8, 'H' UNION ALL
    SELECT  9, 'I' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'J' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'K' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'L' UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 'M'
  ) x (CatNum, CatName)
ORDER BY
  Category,
  Primaykey;
```

Here are the results that the above script produced for me:

- `tblCat`:

  ```
  PrimaryKey  Category
  ----------- --------------------------------------------------
  1           A
  2           B
  3           C
  4           D
  5           E
  6           F
  7           G
  8           H
  9           I
  10          J
  11          K
  12          L
  13          M
  ```
- `tblCatDataNew`:

  ```
  PrimaryKey  FK_CatID    Data
  ----------- ----------- -----------
  1           1           1
  2           1           1
  3           1           5
  4           2           2
  5           2           2
  6           2           2
  7           3           3
  8           3           5
  9           3           3
  10          4           5
  11          4           5
  12          4           5
  13          5           5
  14          5           5
  15          5           5
  16          6           5
  17          6           5
  18          6           5
  19          7           3
  20          7           3
  21          7           5
  22          8           3
  23          8           5
  24          8           3
  25          9           3
  26          9           3
  27          9           3
  28          10          1
  29          10          1
  30          10          1
  31          11          4
  32          11          1
  33          11          1
  34          12          1
  35          12          5
  36          12          1
  37          13          1
  38          13          1
  39          13          4
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to unpivot the columns, and `select ... into` to store the result in a new table:

```
select  PrimaryKey
,       FK_CatId
,       Category
into    tblCatDataNew
from    (
        select  PrimaryKey
        ,       1
        ,       A
        from    tblCatData
        union all
        select  PrimaryKey
        ,       2
        ,       B
        from    tblCatData
        union all
        ...
        )
```